# Change android SpannableString link text color when pressed

Tags: android

How to change text color of a link when pressed(Touch or pressed effect). Please see my code below

**Code:**

```
SpannableString spanStr =  new SpannableString(tag);     
spanStr.setSpan(new  HashTagsClickableSpan(tag), 0, tag.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanStr.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,tag.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

class HashTagsClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{    
   String clicked;
   public HashTagsClickableSpan(String string) {
      super();
      clicked =string;
   }

   public void onClick(View tv) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Text = " + clicked,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
   }

   @Override
   public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
      ds.setUnderlineText(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClickableSpan.onClick` is only called after the `ACTION_UP`, so it's probably too late for the effect you want.  In general, you can call `View.invalidate()` to issue a redraw (and another call to `updateDrawState`).

To get a nice pressed effect, you're probably better off registering a touch listener with [`View.setOnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) , listening for the mouse events directly, modifying your custom span state if necessary, and posting an invalidate.